# return different type than generic defined one Error: "Cannot implicity convert type List<A> to List<tableType>"

Tags: c#, generics

I have generic function which returns List of generic type, but in some case I want to return stored list of elements of type A. I got "Cannot implicitly convert type `List<A>` to `List<tableType>`":

```
    private List<A> allGroupsHolder = null;

    public List<tableType> GetAllObjects<tableType>() where tableType : class
    {
        if (typeof(tableType) == typeof(Group))
        {
            if (groupHolderState)
            {
                groupHolderState = true;
                var t = db.GetTable<Group>();
                allGroupsHolder = t.ToList();
            }
            return allGroupsHolder;
        }

        var table = db.GetTable<tableType>();
        return table.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: Is it feasible to change `List<tableType>` to `IEnumerable<tableType>` for your task so your function just returns IEnumerable? Also what is `A` in your case? Is it some class derived form `tableType`?

Comment: I can, but the problem is in converting A to tableType.

Comment: You probably wanna say `return allGroupsHolder.Cast<tableType>();`

Comment: @MarkH your answer is ok, but I also have change List to IEnumerable.

Comment: @MarkH could you write down your answer, I don't want to steal your points ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MarkH and @Blablablaster helped me solve this with comments.

I had to change returned type to `IEnumerable` and use `Cast`

```
private List<A> allGroupsHolder = null;

public IEnumerable<tableType> GetAllObjects<tableType>() where tableType : class
{
    if (typeof(tableType) == typeof(Group))
    {
        if (groupHolderState)
        {
            groupHolderState = true;
            var t = db.GetTable<Group>();
            allGroupsHolder = t.ToList();
        }
        return allGroupsHolder.Cast<tableType>();
    }

    var table = db.GetTable<tableType>();
    return table.ToList();
}
```

Thank you fellows.